# Digital Audio Resampling

Tags: python, resampling, digital, sinc

I've been working from this reference [document](https://dl.icdst.org/pdfs/files/89b500288dc19beaa7dfd1c77ce800c3.pdf), essentially trying to recreate Figure 7 with the understanding that the two functions `place_signal` and `signal_shift` were able to undo one another.
[image]

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def place_signal(size,location,signal,sinc_length=100):

    bin = int(np.floor(location))
    delta = location - bin

    x = np.zeros(size,dtype=np.complex128)
    for idx in range(-sinc_length,sinc_length):
        # skip indexes that are invalid
        if bin+idx<0 or bin+idx>=size:
            continue

        temp = np.pi*(idx+delta)
        x[bin+idx]+= signal*np.sin(temp)/temp

    return x
        
def signal_shift(original, shift):
    orig_fft = np.fft.fft(original)
    phases = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, len(original)) * shift
    shift = np.exp(complex(0, 1) * phases)
    result_fft = orig_fft * shift
    return np.fft.ifft(result_fft)

size = 128
location = 64.5
signal = complex(1,0)
offset = location - np.floor(location)

x0 = place_signal(size,location,signal)
x1 = np.zeros(size,dtype=np.complex128)
x1[int(size/2)] += signal

y0 = signal_shift(x0,offset)
y1 = signal_shift(x1,offset)
y2 = signal_shift(y1,offset)

plt.plot(np.real(x0),label="Place Signal")
plt.plot(np.real(y1),label="Sample Shift")
plt.legend()
plt.grid("on")
plt.show()


plt.plot(np.real(y0),label="Place Signal shifted back")
plt.plot(np.real(y2),label="Signal shift shifted back")
plt.legend()
plt.grid("on")
plt.show()
```

The first plot shows how a signal can be placed/shifted by half a sample using both functions.
[image]

The second plot shows how the `signal_shift` is used on both signals to shift them by 0.5 samples.
[image]

The signal moved with `signal_shift` is back in its original position (albeit with a negative sign), but the signal generated by `place_signal` does not compress the same way, and I don't understand why.

Any help would be very appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Michael. I'm reading this really quickly without time at the moment to go through your code, but since there's no activity I'll comment in case it's helpful that my first thought is for you to zero pad your FFT's (which then approach the continuous frequency IDFT) where you might find more insight as the samples given are on the same IDFT. What you see here is the subsampled IDFT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21830878/shift-the-elements-of-a-vector-by-non-integer-shift-in-matlab), which shows that I had missed an `fftshift` of the phases vector in my `signal_shift` function.